# In GTK, how do I get the actual size of a widget on screen?

Tags: python, api, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

First I looked at the `get_size_request` method. The docs there end with:

> To get the size a widget will actually use, call the `size_request()` instead of this method.

I look at `size_request()`, and it ends with

> Also remember that the size request is not necessarily the size a widget will actually be allocated.

So, is there any function in GTK to get what size a widget actually is? This is a widget that is on-screen and actually being displayed, so GTK definitely has this information somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be it (took some time to find):

> The get_allocation() method returns a gtk.gdk.Rectangle containing the bounds of the widget's allocation.

From [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-allocation).

Comment: this looks promising! i'll check it out. you'd think it would be easier to find... like have one of the words "size" "bounds" "width" etc in the function name.

Comment: ...although "will actually be allocated" gives a tiny hint, now that I look at it.